Cannot use .env properly with mongodb
I want to use .env variables for my server-side but index.js can see .env but does not run mongo properly. I can log .env variables from index.js also if i define port and url statically in index.js everything going well.

const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const authRoute = require("./Routes/AuthRoute");
require("dotenv").config();
const {MONGO_URL,PORT} = process.env;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
  

  }).then(() => console.log("MongoDB is  connected successfully"))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  }));

  app.use(cookieParser());

  app.use(express.json());
  
  app.use("/", authRoute);

MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://admin:admin@app.mcv3k.mongodb.net/? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=app;
PORT=4000;

My .env file also at root directory
I also try to make MONGO_URL to string in .env but it doesn't worked.
I want to use mongo url dynamically via .env but i couldn't figure it out.

dotenv loads environment variables into process.env. Maybe it is not clear form the code example, but you should be calling process.env.MONGO_URI if loaded from .env file

I also tried process.emv.MONGO_URI but error is same.

Do you really have a newline in your .env file, or is that that a pasting inssue in Stack Overflow?

no , mongo_uri is single line. just a pasting issue.

Also, remove the spaces around =, like MONGO_URI=mongodb+... and not MONGO_URI = mongodb+..., and PORT=4000 instead of PORT = 4000

I'm voting to close because the issue is caused by a typo.

I just solved the problem. The problem was Express 4.x , now treats app.listen() as an asynchronous operation, so listener.address() will only return data inside of app.listen()'s callback. If I declare port statically, code going well but it is also not good usage because it still static.

How is this an answer when you are still facing an issue with using the env file? Are you fairly certain that this is an issue with Express 4 and that you have tried out the steps other users have laid out in the comments?

yes, I was tried that before asking to stackoverflow. Then now i realize, its not an issue about reading .env ( i can log it). I suppose that app.listen() going to event loop and not compatible with .env cause of .env reading port statically.

It looks like a typo with the declarations. MONGO_URI is different from MONGO_URL.
You can try declaring both MONGO_URI and MONGO_URL variables in your .env file if you have a tendency to use both variables, even though this is not a good practice.

No, I just preview the 2 way i tired on this code. I am trying just one of them. Also there is no typo error. When i declare from .env, I've got eaddrinuse error but if i paste the same code to the index.js, it going well
